Excel: Transforming automatically a cell based on the input in another one
I'm creating a database. Column A contains different elements. Column B is a ".type" column, so I need to assign one number to each of those elements and that number needs to be consistent across the whole database, as follows:



Column A
Column B




Cow
1


Chicken
2


Horse
3


Butterfly
4


Cow
1



I need a way to make column B take the number corresponding to each one of the elements of column A. Is there a way to do this with an excel function?
I've tried the IF function, but doesn't seem to work for my purposes, perhaps because I have several elements.
It works with only one value and I know which number it's got attributed. For instance:
=IF(A5="Cow", "1", "False")
For this reason, I tried to use multiple arguments, as explained here: Change value in a cell based on value in another cell
However, it gave me error. It said that I had used too many arguments. Example to follow:
=IF(A5="Cow", "1", "False", IF(A5="Chicken", "2", "False"))
Is it possible to do what I want to do? For the values in Column B to be automatically populated when an element in Column A is included, while having several (more than 6) elements in Column A?

=IF(A5="Cow", "1", "False", IF(A5="Chicken", "2", "False")) has too many arguments indeed, IF only takes 3 arguments, the test (A5=Cow), a return for TRUE (1) and a return for FALSE, in your case "FALSE"; to do what you wanted, you have to change the "FALSE" for a new IF (this is called a nested IF); So it'd look like this: =IF(A5="Cow", "1", IF(A5="Chicken", "2", "False")); You can replace the "FALSE" instance each time with a new IF, until you get to the last, or use IFS which would be something like =IFS(A5="cow",1,A5="Chicken",2,....)

Also, you don't need to (but you can) put the result (1, 2, 3, ...) in quotation marks, this will transform them into text, which makes it harder to do calculations with them later on. However, if it's actual text, or you want the numbers to be formatted to text, then use the quotation marks.

You might want to use a different approach instead of nesting IF : =MATCH(B2,{"Cow","Chicken","Horse","Butterfly"},0) (use Ctrl+shift+enter entering the formula when using older Excel).

=LET(a,UNIQUE($A$1:$A$9),b,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(a)),,1,1),XLOOKUP(A1,a,b,,0))

Drag it down or:
=LET(c,A1:A9,a,UNIQUE(c),b,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(a)),,1,1),MAP(c,LAMBDA(z,XLOOKUP(z,a,b,,0))))

Result:


This should fix your formula, you don't want a False argument for each test. If the test is false, then you want to start the next IF formula:
=IF(A5="Cow", "1", IF(A5="Chicken", "2", "False"))

You could also use the IFS formula if you want to use multiple nested IF statements
And, maybe a good way to do this would be with XLOOKUP
=XLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)



I know this question already has an accepted answer, and that answer is based on the UNIQUE() function, but why the Let() and the XLookup() ...?
My proposal simply uses this formula: =MATCH(A1;UNIQUE(A$1:A$10);0)
Hereby a screenshot of the results:

